# How to write special keyboard character in latex?

Tags: symbols, characters

I wonder if it is possible to write character Ł on latex.
I try with `$\Ł$` but it does not work.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure the generic symbols duplicate is good for characters supported in the default UTF-8 inputenc setup. (despite the `$` in the question I don't think this is a math symbol question)

Answer (score 5):

The traditional markup (going back to plain TeX) is `\L` but in any recent latex installation you can simply use Ł

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Ł 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get with the help of [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\L
\end{document}
```

[image]